NPM passport issue
I am using NPM package passport
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("users/login.ejs");
});

router.post(
    "/login",
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
    },
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        failureRedirect: "/login",
        failureFlash: true,
    }),
    async (req, res) => {
        res.send("Welcome You are logged in!");
    }
);


In ejs I am having a login page that is taking input of username and password in the from with a method POST
when I am trying the /login POST request then the req.body is printed
 { username: 'username', password: 'pass' }
but the page keep loading no response is shown even when the username password are correct

Does it work if you remove the async part?

No, The page is still stuck on loading

I think that might be because you are redirecting to POST /login instead of GET /login

How to correct that

Or you might configured your strategy incorrectly

I was watching a tutorial in that it was like this only
How to configure the strategy

There is some issue in passport.authenticate

you need to add express-session ,  passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser in your code. check this link out  https://medium.com/@prashantramnyc/node-js-with-passport-authentication-simplified-76ca65ee91e5
